# Command/query instead of repository

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm thinking about implementation of command/query pattern and I have following solution:

Interface for queries:

```
public interface IQuery<TResult, TArg> 
    where TResult: class 
    where TArg: class
{
    TResult Execute(TArg query);
}
```

Implementation:

```
 public class TreesTransQuery : IQuery<List<Trans>, GetTree>
    {
        private readonly DatabaseContext _context;
        public TreesTransQuery(DatabaseContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public List<Trans> Execute(GetTree query)
        {
            return _context.Trans
                .Where(x => 
                    _context.Trees
                        .Where(z => z.Id == query.TreeId)
                        .Union
                        ( _context.Trees
                            .Where(z => z.Id == query.TreeId)
                            .SelectMany(z => z.Children)
                        ).Select(z => z.Id)
                    .Any(q => x.Entity == $"{q}tree"))
                    .ToList();
        }
    }
```

Execution(in service layer)

```
    var result = new TreesTransQuery(_context).Execute(query);
```

where "query" is instance of GetTree class which is below:

```
public class GetTree
{
    public int TreeId { get; set; }
}
```

It works good, but I'm not sure if this solution is correct.
What exactly should be GetTree and TransTreeQuery classes?

I'm assuming that the TransTreeQuery is implementation of query, but what about GetTree? This class represents params for query, so how should I call this class? GetTreeParams? TreeTransQueryParams?

TreeTransQuery - implementation of query

GetTree - ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? What kind of separataion you have in mind? Right now, you could replace the whole query with single method and nothing would change.

Comment: In my opinion bloated repository, with dozens of methods is not a good pattern. But single query/command (which in repository is represented by single method) is better. It represents single query/command and doesn't have houndred lines of code.

Comment: As it's stand I don't really like it, you have a class called GetTree, so why not having both the parameter and the query define in that class ? Then you can pass that object to your repository that will execute it within a proper transaction. So basically your repository will handle everything related to the connection of your database and the mapping of data.

Comment: @Walfrat because `GetTree` acts as a DTO in this case. If it were to be a single class, and you use it as a parameter in a controller action the model binder won't be able to construct it as it probably has some dependencies.

Comment: The problem is that your DTO seems specific to that query since it's called `GetTree`. So I supposed you would have one class like `GetTree` and one command class for each of your query.

Answer (score 2):

In my view this is a bad idea.

First lets consider naming. Your TransTreeQuery contains the logic for retrieving a list of Trans. Essentially it is a Repository and your IQuery interface makes it a generic repository.

A query pattern, in my view, is what you have with the linq in the execute method. It allows the caller to define the query rather than having a set of predefined queries which can be executed.

Now, a generic repository is considered bad because it cant expose per type method names. All your operations are now called Get() or Add() or in your case Execute().

You avoid this problem by having just a single method per class, so you can use the class name to indicate functionality. But its hard to see how this will be used in an application. Will you collect them in a ITransRepository with multiple named methods? why bother with the Interface in that case? Passing multiple query objects around your app will increase its complexity a lot.

The Query pattern (as in your Linq) is also considered bad because it tends to link you to the underlying database implementation. Queries you write in your abstracted query objects might not be performant or even possible to run on all databases, so you end up linking your application code (where the query is defined) to your database query language.

In conclusion, your proposed pattern would seem to be a repository wrapping generic repositories wrapping a queryable repository.

You will exchange Methods and parameters for Classes. While this will split your Repository logic over several sub classes making it potentially more readable, you will have dozens of extra classes to manage.

It seems this goal could be achieved in other ways. Lose the interface and parameter class for example and keep your 'Query' class internal to the Repository. Maybe it can even have a static method?

Comment: I don't want to create a generic repository. As you said I want to split traditional repository to multiple query or command object, which single query/command replaces method in repository.

Comment: "Essentially it is a Repository and your IQuery interface makes it a generic repository." Except it's not. A repository encapsulates a list of domain objects and all operations that can be performed on them. A generic repository supports all 4 main operations. The query handler implementation supports just **one** operation, on a **single** type.

Comment: "a generic repository is considered bad because it cant expose per type method names". Yet the big guys use it. See EF's context class.

Comment: MS cant write your repo for you, the only thing they can do is make a generic queryable repo for mssql. You have to choose where you put your data acess logic.

Comment: perhaps it would be more correct to say the IQuery interface is an interface to a limited form of generic repository. Sure it encapsulates the query and gives you that separation. But I think its not a very elegant way of doing it. Maybe add an example of how the application uses it?

Comment: I'm using something very similar to [this](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2015/05/05/cqrs-with-mediatr-and-automapper). Which doesn't look much different than what the OP is trying to do. If you mix CQS with SRP this is what you get.

Comment: hmm, it looks like you have no repository at all and no place for business logic? The point of the repo is to separate the db from the business logic. If you have commands/queries as well, they would encapsulate the repo. not the other way around. (as I think one of your commenters hints at)

Comment: Also, when you think about the amount of extra code you introduce in your example, its huge! If you had a repository with those two methods on it so your controllers were already thin. It would hardly simplfy the solution to split that repo into the individual functions and add all the orchestration

Answer (score 1):

The solution is correct. `TransTreeQuery` is the handler of the `GetTree` query. It can use the ORM directly or through an abstraction (repository). `GetTree` is a [parameter object](http://wiki.c2.com/?ParameterObject). You can add a parameter of this type to the controller action that receives the query and have the framework bind the request parameters to the properties of this object.

Usually, queries and their handlers should share a part of their name. You could have something like `TransTreeQuery` (instead of `GetTree`) and `TransTreeQueryHandler` (instead of `TransTreeQuery`). The same goes for commands.